# Implement quantum teleportation in qiskit

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

I am trying to implement the [quantum teleportation protocol](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/teleportation.html) from the qiskit textbook in qiskit: 
I start with q_0 bit = 1 and I expect that  q_3 = 1 at the end but it does not work.

```
from qiskit import *

qc = QuantumCircuit(3, 3)

qc.x(0) #q -> 1
qc.barrier()

qc.h(1)
qc.cx(1, 2)
qc.barrier()
# Next, apply the teleportation protocol.
qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.h(0)
qc.barrier()
# We measure these qubits and use the classical results to perform an operation
qc.measure(0, 0)
qc.measure(1, 1)
qc.cx(1, 2)
qc.cz(0, 2)
#qc.barrier()
backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
job = execute(qc, backend, shots=1, memory=True).result()
result = job.get_memory()[0]
qc.measure(2, 2)
print(job.get_memory()[0]) #q = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is working as intended. In the textbook, it says towards the end of the code cell:

*In principle, if the teleportation protocol worked, we have q[2] = secret_unitary|0>
As a result, we should be able to recover q[2] = |0> by applying the reverse of secret_unitary
since for a unitary u, u^dagger u = I.*

You had your `secret_unitary` as 'x', which does in fact change Alice's first qubit to 1. But, at the end of the circuit, the dagger of the secret_unitary is applied, cancelling the original application of the `secret_unitary`. You should expect to see 0 for q[2], as that means that the state from q[0] (in this case, 1) was successfully teleported to q[2], and then brought back to 0 by the dagger of the `secret_unitary`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

From your code, I have got the circuit. I think the reason that can not get q_3 rightly. Is " Qubit measurement is followed by instructions".After the measurement, you can't do operations anymore.
But I'm not sure this is the reason or not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with the `qc.measure(2, 2)` which is performed after the execution of the circuit `job = execute(qc, backend, shots=1, memory=True).result()`.  Everything added after the execute is ignored because you run the circuit at the `execute` statement.

To fix it you can anticipate the measurement before the execution:

```py
from qiskit import *

qc = QuantumCircuit(3, 3)

qc.x(0) #q -> 1
qc.barrier()

qc.h(1)
qc.cx(1, 2)
qc.barrier()
# Next, apply the teleportation protocol.
qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.h(0)
qc.barrier()
# We measure these qubits and use the classical results to perform an operation
qc.measure(0, 0)
qc.measure(1, 1)
qc.cx(1, 2)
qc.cz(0, 2)
#qc.barrier()
qc.measure(2, 2)  # <--- anticipated
backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
job = execute(qc, backend, shots=1, memory=True).result()
result = job.get_memory()[0]
print(job.get_memory()[0]) #q = 0
```

I hope it helps.
Cheers